# Почему редактируется только конкретный пользователь?

Tags: логика, php

Здравствуйте

Пользуюсь функцией и не понимаю, как это всё происходит... помогите разобраться.

Есть база `tb_user`, где есть много пользователей... и есть поле username, где хранятся имена пользователей.

Дальше код:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_user") or die(mysql_error());
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 $username = $res["username"];
 echo "
  <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "$username" />
  <input type = "submit" name = "save" value = "Сохранить" />
  <hr />
 ";
}

if(isset($_POST["save"])){
 mysql_query("UPDATE tb_user SET username = '" .$_POST["username"] ."'") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

И фишка в том, что редактируется именно тот пользователь, возле которого я нажал на кнопку, ведь название текстового поля username у всех одинаковое, а редактируется только нужный... вот не понимаю, как тут всё происходит.

Comment: Это не весь код, иначе зацепило бы все записи.

Answer (score 3):

Очень просто - выборка всех пользователей генерирует в цикле html для формы - кода формы конечно и ее экшна я пока не вижу - но вырисовывается вполне нормальная картинка.. Сгенерированный код - обвешивает какую то кнопку.. И при редактировании точнее при нажатии происходит POST запрос на страничку, как я понимаю на эту же..

Но правда затрагивает всех пользователей - сразу потому что в запросе

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tb_user SET username = '" .$_POST["username"] ."'")
```

нету параметра

```
WHERE [condition]
```

и так во первых нужен еще один параметр  - его в мускуле называют primarykey - этот параметр не уникален. Этот параметр (назовем его Id) служит обычно критерием для работы с данными содержащимися в этой строке..
выводить его нужно еще одним инпутом и в вашем случае кодом `$id = $res['id'];`

```
<input type = "text" name = "id" value = "$id" />
```

а проверять

```
if(isset($_POST["save"])){
 mysql_query("UPDATE tb_user SET username = '" .$_POST["username"] ."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

}
Тогда редактирование будет присуще одному человеку кому собственно принадлежит кнопка...

Answer (score 2):

Если я верно понял автора то ему нужна конструкция вида

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["save"])){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_user") or die(mysql_error());
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 mysql_query("UPDATE tb_user SET username = '" .$_POST["username".$user_id] ."' where id=".$user_id) or die(mysql_error());
}}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_user") or die(mysql_error());
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

 $username = $res["username"];
 echo '
  <input type = "text" name = "username'.$user_id.'" value = "'.$username.'" />
  <input type = "submit" name = "save" value = "Сохранить" />
  <hr />
 ';
}
?>
```

В итоге получим редактирование всех пользователей по нажатию ЛЮБОЙ кнопкри сохранить... опущена фильтрация параметров (что важно добавить) и такие мелочи как собрать это дело в форму....)

Пы.сы. от копипаста код не заработает)) не хватает объявления кое-каких переменных) но думаю доковыряете) код интуитивно понятен)